# "Unable to access 'https://github.com/flutter/flutter.git/': Failed to connect to github.com port 8080:"

Tags: git, flutter, github

This the error I am getting when I upgrade my flutter SDK:

[image]

```
ProcessException: Process exited abnormally:
fatal: unable to access 'https://github.com/flutter/flutter.git/': Failed to connect to 127.0.0.1 port 8080: Connection refused
  Command: git fetch --tags
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved it like this;
start windows>edit system environment variables>environment variables
There were illogical/wrong operations that I added to the user variables and system variables sections (For example JAVA_HOME, 127.0.0.1 url etc). I deleted them. Then it got better.

Answer (score -1):

Looks to just be an internet connectivity issue. On a similar message, I simply tried again from a room with a better connection, and it worked.

If it seems you should be online, to begin debugging your connection to GitHub you could start with `ping https://github.com`.